# dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of

Tags: sudo

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of adtf-2.13.2:
 adtf-2.13.2 depends on libsdl1.2-dev; however:
  Package libsdl1.2-dev is not installed.
 adtf-2.13.2 depends on libasound2-dev; however:
  Package libasound2-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package adtf-2.13.2 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 adtf-2.13.2
```

Comment: does `sudo apt-get install -f`help at all?

Comment: package libsdl1.2-dev exists (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libsdl1.2-dev) - you could ` apt-cache policy libsdl1.2-dev` to see if your system can find it; but it could be the command you used to install it (you didn't say) was wrong, or version of os (not said) & other things you didn't tell us..